# Using meteorjs how can I identify discrete connected clients?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I want to be able to treat each connected client differently based on some conditions but I can't seem to figure out how to target an individual client. I would need some kind of unique reference per client but I can't find it either on the client itself or on the server as part of a pub/sub interaction or otherwise.

I noticed you could get a userId but that depends on the user actually creating an account and signing in, otherwise it remains set to null.

How would I, for example, only show a message on the most recent client to connect, or set up a queuing system to give connected clients access to a limited resource?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `this.setUserId()` can do what you want:

> Call this function to change the currently logged in user on the connection that made this method call. This simply sets the value of userId for future method calls received on this connection. Pass null to log out the connection.

You can check  if the id is null and if so just set it to some unique identifier.  Place it in first method or publish function that your clients will call.

Info on function and the quote are from http://docs.meteor.com.

Comment: Thanks, I think that should do the trick! I'll try it after work today.

Comment: Also, check out https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-user-status for the full suite of options. It's really good!

Answer (score 0):

You could assign each client a unique identifier and have them update a document every few seconds with a new timestamp. To find the most recent client to connect, sort the document on timestamps and take the first one. If a client stops updating the document, it is disconnected so you can filter it from your connectedClients method or remove it from the document.